# Why I am not able to add new entry in the array of linked list for my hash table?

Tags: java, algorithm, linked-list, hashtable

I am trying to make a simple hash table to learn more about hashing and I am using an array of LinkedList to do so.

Following is the code I am using:

```
public class HashTable {

protected LinkedList<Entry>[] myTable;

  public HashTable(int capacity) {
    if(capacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    myTable = new LinkedList[capacity];
  }

  public void put(String key, Integer value) {
    int index = hash(key);
    //System.out.println(index);

    //if(myTable[index] == null) {
        myTable[index] = new LinkedList<Entry>();
        Entry entry = new Entry(key, value);
        myTable[index].add(entry);
    //}
  }

  public boolean containsKey(String key) {
    int index = hash(key);
    //System.out.println(index);

    for(Entry e : myTable[index]) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey()); // to check which entries are stored
        if(e.getKey().equals(key)) {
            return true;
        }
        }

    return false;
  }

  public Integer get(String key) {
      int index = hash(key);
       //System.out.println(index);

    for(Entry entry : myTable[index]) {
        if(entry.getKey().equals(key)){
            return entry.getValue();
        }
    }

    return null;
  }


  public int getCapacity() {
    return myTable.length;
  }


  public int hash(String item) {
      return item.hashCode()%(this.getCapacity());
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      HashTable hashTable = new HashTable(10);
      hashTable.put("something", 20);
      hashTable.put("new", 21);
      hashTable.put("amazing", 100);

      System.out.println(hashTable.containsKey("something"));
  }

}
```

For the above input I am getting the following output:

> amazing
>   false

I am not able to figure out why am I not able to add new entries to the linked list at an index. I am just storing only one entry at index of 0 for the above inputs, and not others.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: In your `put()` you ony have `if(myTable[index] == null) { ...}` - what if the list for that index already exists which is quite likely if the capacity is 10? Btw, bugs like this should be easily spottable by using a debugger - you just look at what your code is actually doing and what it should do - whenever both are different you've spotted a bug (or a problem in your understanding :) ).

Comment: @Thomas thank you, yes I have updated the code but still I am not getting all the elements from the linked list. I mean, only one Entry is added in index 0 when there should be 3.

Comment: Well, after your edit you are always replacing the list and thus discard every previous content. You basically need to initialize the list if it is null only. Then add elements if they aren't present already (i.e. check whether there's already an entry with that key.

Comment: @Thomas so how should I add a new Entry in the LinkedList at index 0.

Comment: I've updated my comment. Basically if the list you need is null then you first create an _empty_ list. Then you proceed normally, i.e. add entries for missing keys. I'll repeat my suggestion: use a debugger to check what you code is doing.

Comment: @Thomas yes I have figured it out, thank you :)

Comment: First try debugging with a debugger, print statements or even a pen and paper.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new list for every new entry to the hash table. Instead you should create a new list if a list does not exist for the index and if the list exists you should append to the list.

Use the following code to put an element to the hash table.

```
public class HashTable {

protected LinkedList<Entry>[] myTable;

  public HashTable(int capacity) {
    if(capacity < 0)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();

    myTable = new LinkedList[capacity];
  }

  public void put(String key, Integer value) {
    int index = hash(key);
    //System.out.println(index);

    if(myTable[index] == null) {
        myTable[index] = new LinkedList<Entry>();
    }
    Entry entry = new Entry(key, value);
    myTable[index].add(entry);

  }

  public boolean containsKey(String key) {
    int index = hash(key);
    //System.out.println(index);

    for(Entry e : myTable[index]) {
        System.out.println(e.getKey()); // to check which entries are stored
        if(e.getKey().equals(key)) {
            return true;
        }
        }

    return false;
  }

  public Integer get(String key) {
      int index = hash(key);
       //System.out.println(index);

    for(Entry entry : myTable[index]) {
        if(entry.getKey().equals(key)){
            return entry.getValue();
        }
    }

    return null;
  }


  public int getCapacity() {
    return myTable.length;
  }


  public int hash(String item) {
      return item.hashCode()%(this.getCapacity());
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
      HashTable hashTable = new HashTable(10);
      hashTable.put("something", 20);
      hashTable.put("new", 21);
      hashTable.put("amazing", 100);

      System.out.println(hashTable.containsKey("something"));
  }

}
```

> Method hashCode()  will generate negative values also.

You will get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExcception when accessing the hash table(i.e. when using myTable[index]).

To handle negative indices use

```
public int hash(String item) {
      return Math.abs(item.hashCode()%(this.getCapacity()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

update your hash code to below. it should work.

```
  public int hash(String item) {
    return (this.getCapacity() - 1) & item.hashCode();
  }
```

Here we are doing the bitwise **AND** operation with the actual hash code of key and table capacity. this will make sure the inner bound of table capacity.

**NOTE:** The same hash may be generated for more than one key. you need to elaborate the logic to handle this situation.